# add new row to data frame with list type column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to have multiple elements per cell in a particular column of a data frame. There is [a note at R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/populating-data-frame-cells-with-more-than-one-value/) explaining how to do so with lists:

```
> d <- data.frame(id=1:2)
> d$name <- list(c("Bond", "James"),c("Poppins", "Mary"))
> d
  id          name
1  1   Bond, James
2  2 Poppins, Mary
```

So far so good. But now I would like to add further rows to the data frame. This is the result:

```
> d[nrow(d) + 1,] <- list(3, c("Hood", "Robin"))
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nrow(d) + 1, , value = list(3, c("Hood",  :
  replacement element 2 has 2 rows to replace 1 rows
> d
  id          name
1  1   Bond, James
2  2 Poppins, Mary
3  3          Hood
```

The second element of the vector is discarded. How can I convince R to add the second element to the name cell too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `add_row`

```
library(tibble)
add_row(d, id = 3, name = list(c('Bond', 'Robbin')))
#  id          name
#1  1   Bond, James
#2  2 Poppins, Mary
#3  3  Bond, Robbin
```

---

Regarding the way to assign next row, we have a `list` of `list` as the 2nd column

```
d[nrow(d) + 1, ] <- list(3, list(c("Hood", "Robbin")))
d
#  id          name
#1  1   Bond, James
#2  2 Poppins, Mary
#3  3  Hood, Robbin
```